# Does gMaps APIv3 allow you to use two overlay map types and how?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I've been looking for the solution to make two (or more) layers visible using informations from WMS servers. I am using **overlayMapTypes**  array to make it work (you can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) ) pushing overlays onto it. The issue is - even when I push two layers there, only the latter (on highest position number) layer is visible. Here's the code I use (I've cut not-important info).

```
function addLayer(layers, serverUrl){

mapPref.currentLayers = layers;
mapPref.layersServerUrl = serverUrl;    

  var wmsOptions = {
  //here I am initializing layer object - its max/min zoom, gettile function, size of
  //tile, alternative text, etc.
  };

  wmsMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(wmsOptions);

  mapPref.cmsMap.overlayMapTypes.push(wmsMapType);
  };
```

Is there any way to deal with it that way? Or should I look somewhere else?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a link to your site?

Comment: It's not yet published, we still need to get jboss server with public IP. If you need any details I will do my best :)

Comment: set up a jsfiddle or jsbin so we can see your attempts and edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've already figured it out - it was all about this line

```
mapPref.layersServerUrl = serverUrl;
```

When I overwrote this variable (it was like global variable) - every layer I added earlier from another server lost their connection (I was trying to get layers don't exist)

But thank you all for trying to help me - I really appreciate it! :)